# Postgres psql command intermittently 'stalls' in powershell

Tags: powershell, postgresql-14, windows-11

I'm in the process of moving a postgres database to a new server.

I have number of large tables, partitioned by month, each contains several 10's of millions of rows.

I have a powershell script to do the following....

- Copy the backup file (for a single partition) from archive location
  (using robocopy)
- load the file back into the database using psql.
- drop the backup file.
- loop back to the beginning and move onto the
  next partition.

Copying the file from the archive takes maybe 10 minutes, loading it typically 40 minutes, then it moves onto the next partition. **The problem** is that the PowerShell console seems to occasionally get 'stuck' after loading a partition. Occasionally, a partition seems to be taking too long (say an hour) I check the windows task manager, and none of the processes seem to be doing anything.  I check the dashboard in pgAdmin4 (no locks, most sessions idle). Then I check the record count for the partition being loaded - the record count seems to be static (still the same 5 minutes later). So as far as I can tell the partition has been loaded successfully, and the database is mostly idle. But the powershell console that's running the load session hasn't changed, then I shift focus to the powershell console, press return a couple of times and suddenly it bursts into life. The console tells me it's moved onto the partition, the task-manager indicates that the powershell process and postgres process are now running again, pgAdmin4 also indicates the database has sprung back into life.

The powershell script logs to screen using `Write-host` and the current time between each step, so I always know what the most recent step was. My conclusion is that the interaction between powershell and psql is somehow 'broken' - powershell hasn't worked out that psql has finished and doesn't know to move onto the next step.

Other info - there's no sign of any errors (that I can spot) all the tables seem to get populated correctly (eventually) and the script works fine on all the smaller partitions. This only happens on about 1 partition in 10, the only cure seems to be pressing enter a couple of times.

This isn't a critical problem, occasionally hitting enter a couple of times is a viable solution, but an understanding of what might be going on (or even a solution) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - found a solution.

Need to alter the properties for the powershell console. untick both the boxes `quick edit mode` and `insert mode`